# How do I refer to or call an `if` statement that returns `True`?

Tags: python

How do I refer to or call an `if` statement that returns `True`?  I want to use that conditional to carry out another command.

```
def win(self):
    sent_by_bot = self.sender in self.bots
    is_giveaway = ('giveaway' in self.msg.lower())
    is_win = ('won' in self.msg.lower())
    is_me = ('AAAAA' in self.msg.lower())

    if sent_by_bot and is_giveaway and is_win and is_me:
        return True

    return false
```

Comment: Just for readability: You don't need to write `is_win = ('won' in self.msg.lower())`. Just use `is_win = 'won' in self.msg.lower()`.

Comment: Just for readability: write `return <condition>` ( instead of `if <condition> return True; return False`).

Answer (score 2):

You use the function result as you would any other Boolean value:

```
if my_bot.win():
    <other command>
```